# Convert MS Word Content to HTML

Tags: c#

I need to make an upload tool where in the Word document will be converted to HTML format for saving to database. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written one (see the [Doc to HTML Converter](http://www.modeltext.com/word/index.aspx)).

To implement it, I downloaded the [PIAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax7sdch.aspx) for Word, which let me open a document using Word, and control the format in which Word then re-saves the document.

Alternatively (instead of doing it yourself) there are tools like mine (and others, more famous) which you can use (some of which don't even use Word).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I just wrote an app that converts a Word-doc to a usable web-page. The app provides some of the requirements in the OP.

The app is [WordWebNav (WWN)](https://jimyuill.com/software/www/WordWebNav/). It's free and open-source.

WWN provides a Word VBA program that converts Word-docs to Word-HTML.

WWN also provides a Python program that converts the Word-HTML to a usable web-page:

- It adds missing features to the Word-HTML, e.g., a navigation pane.
- And, WWN fixes some common bugs in Word's HTML, e.g., mis-formatted lists, and overly-wide paragraphs.

The Python program uses a CLI, and it can be called externally.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a client application and you have access to Word, why not automate Word? Word can save in HTML (although you will probably have to clean the HTML up a bit). However, I will warn you that this is not very portable; whoever is going to use application will need to have the same version of Word you developed it with.